# Pickling a staticmethod in Python

Tags: python, static-methods, pickle

I've been trying to pickle an object which contains references to static class methods.
Pickle fails (for example on `module.MyClass.foo`) stating it cannot be pickled, as `module.foo` does not exist.
I have come up with the following solution, using a wrapper object to locate the function upon invocation, saving the container class and function name:

```
class PicklableStaticMethod(object):
    """Picklable version of a static method.
    Typical usage:
        class MyClass:
            @staticmethod
            def doit():
                print "done"
        # This cannot be pickled:
        non_picklable = MyClass.doit
        # This can be pickled:
        picklable = PicklableStaticMethod(MyClass.doit, MyClass)
    """
    def __init__(self, func, parent_class):
        self.func_name = func.func_name
        self.parent_class = parent_class
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func = getattr(self.parent_class, self.func_name)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am wondering though, is there a better - more standard way - to pickle such an object?
I do not want to make changes to the global `pickle` process (using `copy_reg` for example), but the following pattern would be great:
    class MyClass(object):
        @picklable_staticmethod
        def foo():
            print "done."

My attempts at this were unsuccessful, specifically because I could not extract the owner class from the `foo` function. I was even willing to settle for explicit specification (such as `@picklable_staticmethod(MyClass)`) but I don't know of any way to refer to the `MyClass` class right where it's being defined.

Any ideas would be great!

Yonatan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
class PickleableStaticMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, fn, cls=None):
        self.cls = cls
        self.fn = fn
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return PickleableStaticMethod(self.fn, cls)
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.cls, self.fn.__name__)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.cls, name = state
        self.fn = getattr(self.cls, name).fn
```

The trick is to snag the class when the static method is gotten from it.

Alternatives: You could use metaclassing to give all your static methods a `.__parentclass__` attribute. Then you could subclass `Pickler` and give each subclass instance its own `.dispatch` table which you can then modify without affecting the global dispatch table (`Pickler.dispatch`). Pickling, unpickling, and calling the method might then be a little faster.

Comment: this will not work if the original class is not available, which (i think) defeats the purpose of pickling and unpickling a static method - you allow it to be pickled, but you need the whole class to unpickle it.

Comment: try that for instance:

import pickle

class MyClass(object):
    @PickleableStaticMethod
    def dosomething(a, b):
        print a, b

pickled = pickle.dumps(MyClass.dosomething)

del MyClass

stm = pickle.loads(pickled)

Comment: i think I might just have said something totally wrong there, pickle works totally different with funcs that i expected. ignore my latest two comments :-/

Comment: Hi Jason. Could you please explain me 2 things: 1) why _get_ method should be there - I think it could be avoided  2) I think it will not work if cls=None when unpickling

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: modified after Jason comment.

I think python is correct in not letting pickling a staticmethod object - as it is impossible to pickle instance or class methods! Such an object would make very little sense outside of its context:

Check this: [Descriptor Tutorial](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm)

```
import pickle

def dosomething(a, b):
    print a, b

class MyClass(object):
    dosomething = staticmethod(dosomething) 

o = MyClass()

pickled = pickle.dumps(dosomething)
```

This works, and that's what should be done - define a function, pickle it, and use such function as a staticmethod in a certain class.

If you've got an use case for your need, please write it down and I'll be glad to discuss it.

Comment: then the question is not properly written, the OP says "I've been trying to pickle an object which contains references to static class methods" while he's really trying to pickle a static method, not an object containing references to static methods.

Comment: Let me clarify with an example.
I have a task-generation mechanism. For example:
    class MyClass(TaskGenerator):
        @staticmethod
        def certain_task():
            print "task done"
        def generate_task(self):
            return FuncTask(MyClass.certain_task)

I will want to pickle the generated task but currently can't.
I can use a global function - and have until now - but I don't like taking it out from its 'right place' in favor of pickling support.

Comment: I admit I still don't understand *what* you're trying to do, and I still think you might be abusing "static methods" (where, how and why are you unpickling such objects?)