# python multiprocessing - process hangs on join for large queue

Tags: python, process, queue, multiprocessing

I'm running python 2.7.3 and I noticed the following strange behavior. Consider this minimal example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def foo(qin, qout):
    while True:
        bar = qin.get()
        if bar is None:
            break
        qout.put({'bar': bar})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    qin = Queue()
    qout = Queue()
    worker = Process(target=foo,args=(qin,qout))
    worker.start()

    for i in range(100000):
        print i
        sys.stdout.flush()
        qin.put(i**2)

    qin.put(None)
    worker.join()
```

When I loop over 10,000 or more, my script hangs on `worker.join()`. It works fine when the loop only goes to 1,000.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5900985/4013571

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `qout` queue in the subprocess gets full.  The data you put in it from `foo()` doesn't fit in the buffer of the OS's pipes used internally, so the subprocess blocks trying to fit more data.  But the parent process is not reading this data: it is simply blocked too, waiting for the subprocess to finish.  This is a typical deadlock.

Comment: It'd be great if you also offered a code solution to the problem. I.e. how to empty the buffer so the subprocess does not block.

Answer (score 6):

There must be a limit on the size of queues. Consider the following modification:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def foo(qin,qout):
    while True:
        bar = qin.get()
        if bar is None:
            break
        #qout.put({'bar':bar})

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys

    qin=Queue()
    qout=Queue()   ## POSITION 1
    for i in range(100):
        #qout=Queue()   ## POSITION 2
        worker=Process(target=foo,args=(qin,))
        worker.start()
        for j in range(1000):
            x=i*100+j
            print x
            sys.stdout.flush()
            qin.put(x**2)

        qin.put(None)
        worker.join()

    print 'Done!'
```

This works as-is (with `qout.put` line commented out). If you try to save all 100000 results, then `qout` becomes too large: if I uncomment out the `qout.put({'bar':bar})` in `foo`, and leave the definition of `qout` in POSITION 1, the code hangs. If, however, I move `qout` definition to POSITION 2, then the script finishes.

So in short, you have to be careful that neither `qin` nor `qout` becomes too large. (See also: [Multiprocessing Queue maxsize limit is 32767](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900985/multiprocessing-queue-maxsize-limit-is-32767))

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on `python3` when tried to put strings into a queue of total size about 5000 cahrs.

In my project there was a host process that sets up a queue and starts subprocess, then joins. Afrer `join` host process reads form the queue. When subprocess producess too much data, host hungs on `join`. I fixed this using the following function to wait for subprocess in the host process:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty

def yield_from_process(q: Queue, p: Process):
    while p.is_alive():
        p.join(timeout=1)
        while True:
            try:
                yield q.get(block=False)
            except Empty:
                break
```

I read from queue as soon as it fills so it never gets very large

Comment: What is `Empty`?

Comment: @Cuhrazatee Empty is an import from queue and the docs state that: "[Exception raised when non-blocking get() (or get_nowait()) is called on a Queue object which is empty.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Empty)"

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to `.get()` an async worker after the pool had closed

indentation error outside of a with block

**i had this**

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    async_results = list()
    for job in jobs:
        async_results.append(
            pool.apply_async(
                _worker_func,
                (job,),
            )
        )
# wrong
for async_result in async_results:
    yield async_result.get()
```

**i needed this**

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    async_results = list()
    for job in jobs:
        async_results.append(
            pool.apply_async(
                _worker_func,
                (job,),
            )
        )
    # right
    for async_result in async_results:
        yield async_result.get()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this pls. I want to use the result from `get()` after the `with` block.

Comment: @MSS, exiting the with block destroys the pool, meaning all the job results are deleted, so you can copy them into a variable/list that will exist outside the with block, or you can use them inside the with block (or dont use a with block at all, and close the pool manually when you are done)