# Deadlock with big object in multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

When you supply a large-enough object into `multiprocessing.Queue`, the program seems to hang at weird places. Consider this minimal example:

```
import multiprocessing

def dump_dict(queue, size):
  queue.put({x: x for x in range(size)})
  print("Dump finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  SIZE = int(1e5)
  queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  process = multiprocessing.Process(target=dump_dict, args=(queue, SIZE))
  print("Starting...")
  process.start()
  print("Joining...")
  process.join()
  print("Done")
  print(len(queue.get()))
```

If the `SIZE` parameter is small-enough (<= 1e4 at least in my case), the whole program runs smoothly without a problem, but once the `SIZE` is big-enough, the program hangs at weird places. Now, when searching for explanation, i.e. [python multiprocessing - process hangs on join for large queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641887/python-multiprocessing-process-hangs-on-join-for-large-queue/21644038), I have always seen general answers of "you need to consume from the queue". But what seems weird is that the program actually prints `Dump finished` i.e. reaching the code line after putting the object into the `queue`. Furthermore using `Queue.put_nowait` instead of `Queue.put` did not make a difference.

Finally if you use `Process.join(1)` instead of `Process.join()` the whole process finishes **with complete dictionary in the queue** (i.e. the `print(len(..))` line will print `10000`).

Can somebody give me a little bit more insight into this?

Comment: The code is inserting ONE dictionary of 10000 elements in the queue. Is that what you want or are you trying to insert each dict item instead?

Comment: @Pynchia yes, as I was saying I know that I put single huge object in there (it is "dummy" example). What seems weird to me is the behavior of the code (i.e. I would expect to freeze on `Queue.put` and most certainly not "success" if I put timeout there. I was hoping for some kind of explanation (or link for further reading...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `queue.get()` in the parent before you `process.join()` to prevent a deadlock. The queue has spawned a feeder-thread with its first `queue.put()` and the `MainThread` in your worker-process is joining this feeder-thread before exiting. So the worker-process won't exit before the result is flushed to (OS-pipe-)buffer completely, but your result is too big to fit into the buffer and your parent doesn't read from the queue until the worker has exited, resulting in a deadlock.

You see the output of `print("Dump finished")` because the actual sending happens from the feeder-thread, `queue.put()` itself just appends to a `collections.deque` within the worker-process as an intermediate step.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize this mistake, it makes sense now

Comment: Well spotted, of course, nobody else was consuming, only producing... upvoted

Comment: i run the code that you given above, it's fine for just one process, but there are 2 or more processes, deadlock happens again. e.g., ```if __name__ == '__main__':
  SIZE = int(1e5)
  queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  multip = []
  for _ in range(2):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=dump_dict, args=(queue, SIZE))
    multip.append(process)
    print("Starting...")
    process.start()
  print("Joining...")
  print(len(queue.get()))
  for i in range(2):
    multip[i].join()
  print("Done")```

Comment: @dlwu Do you use `queue.get()` only once although you have multiple producers? I can't tell because the formatting isn't clear. But obviously, you would need the same amount of `queue.get()` calls as you have `queue.put()` calls in total, before you can join.

Comment: @Darkonaut ，thanks, you are right,  now it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Facing a similar problem, I solved it using @Darkonaut's answer and the following implementation:

```
import time
done = 0
while done < n:    # n is the number of objects you expect to get
    if not queue.empty():
        done += 1
        results = queue.get()
        # Do something with the results
    else:
        time.sleep(.5)
```

Doesn't feel very pythonic, but it worked!