# executor.map and non-terating parameters

Tags: python, concurrency, lambda, concurrent.futures

I am trying to convert my script from using threads to much cooler multiprocessing (with python 3.2 and `concurrent.futures`, but this piece of code crashes

```
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_THREADS) as executor:
            for result in executor.map(lambda h:
                                       validate_hostname(h, pci_ids, options.verbose),
                                       get_all_hostnames()):
```

I get error `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'function'>: attribute lookup builtins.function failed`. When reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-using-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class) I think the problem is that it is not possible to have lambda function as a parameter of `executor.map()` and in order to make `executor.map()` I would need to develop a one-parameter function, but those `pci_ids` and `options.verbose` are variable so I cannot specify them as fixed values in the help function.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid the pickle error, you must define the function, `validate`, at the top-level of the module or script.

Since the function is being passed to `executor.map` it can only take one argument, so let that argument be a 3-tuple, `(h, pci_ids, verbose)`.

```
def validate(arg):
    h, pci_ids, verbose = arg
    return validate_hostname(h, pci_ids, verbose)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_THREADS) as executor:
    for result in executor.map(validate, [(host, pci_ids, options.verbose)
                                          for host in get_all_hostnames()]):
```

Comment: Worked for me, THX! But one should avoid to instantiate a list when a generator expression is sufficient, thus you should change to `executor.map(validate, ((host, pci_ids, options.verbose) for host in get_all_hostnames()))`