# Run many functions in parallel, and gather all results in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I have a very CPU-intensive function:

```
def entity_intersections(ent, collidable):
    intersections = []

    for line1, line2 in product(ent.shape, collidable.shape):

        pair_intersections = find_intersections(line1 + ent.position, ent.velocity, ent.acceleration, line2 + collidable.position, collidable.velocity, collidable.acceleration, ent, collidable)
        intersections.extend(pair_intersections)

    return intersections
```

I want to make all of the calls to `find_intersections` run in parallel, so that they execute faster, while still gathering all of the results together (once all executions finish).  What library would allow me to do this, given that `find_intersections` is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)?

An example of how to generate these parallel executions, as well as gathering together the results would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your research suggest is an appropriate python library?

Comment: @Marcin For performance enhancement, there's a very large selection: one of several parallel processing libraries (including 2 python built-in libraries), restructuring into coroutines, Cython, etc.  Parallel processing is not my strong point...

Comment: Yes, there are a large number - why not read the documentation of some, and then ask a question when you can't decide between several good candidates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `multiprocessing` module:

```
class FindIntersectionsWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, ent, collidable):
        self.ent = ent
        self.collidable = collidable
    def __call__(self, dims):
        line1, line2 = dims
        return find_intersections(
            line1 + self.ent.position, self.ent.velocity,
            self.ent.acceleration, line2 + self.collidable.position,
            self.collidable.velocity, self.collidable.acceleration, 
            self.ent, self.collidable)

def entity_intersections(ent, collidable):
    find_inter = FindIntersectionsWrapper(ent, collidable)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    return pool.map(find_inter, product(ent.shape, collidable.shape))
```

The helper function `find_intersections_wrapper()` is necessary since `Pool.map()` expects a function with a single argument.

You might want to move the creation of `pool` out of `entity_intersections()` to have the overhead of generating the process pool only once.

**Edit**: Used a class instead of a closure since the callable passed to `Pool.map()` must be picklable on Windows.

Comment: `pool.map` wasn't happy with `wrapper` being defined inside find_intersections, so I generated the list of arguments for `find_intersections` inside `entity_intersections`, and mapped them that way.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @Darthfett: Obviously I couldn't test this code easily.  I'd like to understand what exactly the problem was.  Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows.  The issue is nearly the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3288595/936083).

Comment: @Darthfett: Thanks.  On Linux, this can be resolved by instantiating all necessary closures before creating the process pool, but this won't help on Windows.  (Windows is lacking `fork()`.)

Comment: On Windows, you could use an object instead of a closure -- I'll edit my post later because I don't have time right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `threading` class

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading

This page have some good examples:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Threading doesn't really allow increased CPU utilization with CPython because of the GIL.

Comment: @agf: This is true as long as you are using CPython and don't spend most of the time inside functions releasing the GIL, like NumPy array operations.  I think the more relevant objection here is that you concepttually don't want to use threads here since `find_intersections()` is a pure function.