# How to parallelise a function from another module using python multithreading without pickling it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, libsvm, pool

In my implementation of an svm prediction model, I would like to make the execution of a function `svmutil.svm_train` multi-threaded. Although I'm new to the implementation of multi-threaded programs, I have some knowledge of parallel programming concepts and I believe training multiple models with different sets of parameters simultaneously is theoretically possible.

Setup:

```
import svmutil
import multiprocessing as mp

problem = svm_util.svm_read_problem('my_problem')
# I have a list of svm_param objects I want to train
params = myCode.svm_param_list()

# Calculate the number of worker threads
processes = mp.cpu_count() * 2
```

Split the training into multiple threads of execution:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes)
for param in params:
    pool.apply(svmutil.svm_train, args=(problem, param,))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

However, the problem I'm having is that `svmutil.svm_train` cannot be pickled as it contains a c-type pointer. The python interpreter gives me the error:

```
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

I'd rather adjust my implementation than somehow pickle the function in the module. Therefore, I would like to know, is there some way in which I can parallelise this function without pickling it?

Also, how can I gather the results of the function? Ideally, this would be a list of trained models (output of the function `svmutil.svm_train` for each time I called the function).

Comment: This is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-using-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class

Comment: I wonder if it is really `svmutil.svm_train` or one of the arguments that cannot be pickled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5792404/825093), in the question linked to in the comment above, to build a solution. I was able to parallelise the call to the python function in an external module by spawning pipes and processes and listening for results. The function I pass into the pipe is as follows: `pipe.send(svmutil.svm_train(problem,param)))`