# Installing Python package pathos from git

Tags: python, git, pip, easy-install, pathos

I am trying to install *pathos* library from git, but getting the following error:

```
>pip install https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run

    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundl
e=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 582, in unpack_http
_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 627, in unpack_file
    and is_svn_page(file_contents(filename))):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 210, in file_contents
    return fp.read().decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What is the problem here and how can I get around it?
Thanks

EDIT 1:

Tried the following:

**pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos**

...but still no luck:

```
>pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos
  Cloning https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos to c:\users\gronin\appdata\local\temp\pip-qstvgd-build
Cleaning up...
Cannot find command 'git'
```

EDIT 2:

Tried the following, recommended by **cel**:

**pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos**

...that definitely solved lookup problems (thanks, cel), still having installation issues:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos
Cloning https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos to c:\users\gronin\appdata\loca
l\temp\pip-jldriz-build
Running setup.py (path:c:\users\gronin\appdata\local\temp\pip-jldriz-build\set
up.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos

Downloading/unpacking pp>=1.6.4.4 (from pathos==0.2a1.dev)
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pp>=1.6.4.4 (from pathos==0.2a1.dev)
```

Comment: Try `pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but still no luck. Please, see "EDIT 1:" above in my question.

Comment: You have to install the version control system `git`, before you can use that command in pip.

Comment: I wonder if you also needed to install that package. After trying to install wit git+, I am getting: "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pp>=1.6.4.4 (from pathos==0.2a1.dev)". See "EDIT 2:" in the question above. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: I get the same error, but also the advice to download the dependencies from http://dev.danse.us/packages/ and install them manually. So, just download all dependencies pip cannot satisfy and manually install them with `pip install <path-to-archive-file>`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a long overdue `pathos` release that I need to push out (this month). I'll see what I can do to make it `pip` installable.  There are two main issues: (1) the released versions of the packages are named in a non-standard way (e.g. `0.2.a1-dev`), and (2) several dependencies are forked from other packages, and are only available on http://dev.danse.us/packages.  The temporary workaround for (1) is either to install with the `--pre` flag for `pip` as well as using `git+https`, or to install them manually (`easy_install` actually works).  The workaround for (2) is also as @cel has suggested… download the dependencies and install manually (or use `easy_install`).

This will be sorted out in the stable release. It's basically the blocker issue for getting the release out -- primarily due to (2) above.

Keep track of the status of this issue here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/2

Comment: Note: this should work for now:   `pip install --user git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos`